# Dynamically created 3d images on server on request from web page

Tags: java, web, 3d, jpeg, render

Hi this is my first question here and I hope to get some answers.
I have a project for dynamically creating jpegs (3d rendered images) on request from web page.
The best example of what I'm trying to describe is [www.shoesofprey.com](http://www.shoesofprey.com)
. So I need the part on the server - the 3d rendering stuff. So far I found that this can be done with java 3d and some python apps but I will appreciate any good suggestions or some examples. Please give your answers only on the 3d stuff I know how to proceed and to execute some console level commands formed from the web page but the 3d part is huge problem for me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! 
Your question is quite general. I think you should rather tell what exactly have you tried and maybe add some code
Best regards

Comment: I have php script which will send some get parameters through url to a server which based on this parameter will output an image - rendered in 3d. The parameters could be - x/y orientation of the bag , material of the bag etc. the server (java3d) then will render the image and the script will display it in the html this is the theory and the 3d know how is what I miss.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm being a bit too blunt but it seems like you're looking for a solution where you can pretty much just plug some arguments into and get a 3D render out.

I don't really know how you'll be implementing it but I think different 3D packages such as AutoCAD have command-line prompts which you can use to render a model.

http://www.cadforum.cz/cadforum_en/render-max-files-from-dos-commandline-tip6825

And then call this command via whichever language you're using.

This is CAD specific, but perhaps you can dig around on google and find something relevant to the package you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply , but I think it is not the right approach as 3d studio max and those cad systems are workstation oriented and not serverwise and also the resources they consume are huge and not so optimized for server processing of very basic "sceneless" object like bag for example

Comment: Fair enough. Rendering 3D in general though is not really a simple task in itself. Even though I've seen people perform raytrace renders with PHP I would still assume the language wasn't designed to handle such a purpose. I do know as well that 3D studios max has remote rendering, perhaps you can have a seperate machine which is dedicated to rendering and call that via the remote rendering service so that it doesn't effect your httpd server.

Comment: That is what I need but it is not that solution. The php in fact don't have nothing in common with the 3d itself it only handles the user interaction and "retranslate" it to the "3d" server and as I mentioned the 3dsmax is not universal solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you're trying to do or what you're talking about. What do you actually have done already at this point?

Comment: So far - only the research. I need solution where a "server" will produce jpegs based on predefined simple models and some parameters through cli like orientation ,material etc.

Comment: http://www.renderrocket.com/features/chart/ You can probably make use of an already existing render farm which charges you based on usage, also they're flexible I think with their formats. 

Perhaps you can agree on a format before hand and keep a few generic base scenes which have cameras in different orentations (top, front, left, etc). I would also download an existing open source programs which handle reading 3D formats (for example, Irrlicht3D). You can see how they read from their binary format to be able to modify their materials dynamically.

Comment: Please read carefully the question and if you have the solution then share it render farms are not an option they are completly diferent thing